# Maintain login page when user clicks back button

Tags: php

When an user logs out, and he clicks the back button in the browser, the user can view the page as if they were logged in.

How can I avoid that?

Comment: Could you paste the sample code that you are having trouble with? Then it will be easier for us to figure out why your code is behaving like this.

Comment: In particular, and consistent with @Kmeixner's reply, can you help us know exactly how you/your-code knows that someone is 'logged in'?

Comment: Check out PHP's [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: @Kmeixner : did you have any social acc that i can ask you private ?

Answer (score 1):

In php you can make a session. When an user logs in, you set a variable in that session so that you know that they are logged in, and who they are logged in as. When you log out, you clear the session completely. When you then click the back button, the page is loaded without session cookie, and you'll see the correct behaviour.

This is a very simple example, but it should hopefully give you an idea how to make it work for your website.

login.php

```
//Load an existing session, or create a new session
session_start();

//You probably want to check the passwordhash against a stored
//password hash and only set this when the password was correct    
$_SESSION["uid"] = 12345;
```

test.php (this page will echo "a" when you are logged in, and otherwise "b")

```
//Load an existing session, or create a new session
session_start();

//If the user is logged in, echo "a", otherwise echo "b"
if( isset( $_SESSION["uid"] ) && $_SESSION["uid"] == 12345 ) {
  echo "a";
} else {
  echo "b";
}
```

logout.php

```
//Load an existing session, or create a new session
session_start();

//Remove any information in the session
$_SESSION = array();

//Invalidate the cookie associated with this session (it expires 1 second
//before now)
setcookie( session_name(), '', time() - 1 );

//Finally internally destroy the session. It no longer exists.
session_destroy();
```

Comment: can we talk about it privately ? i have many question want to ask you .

Comment: If something is unclear in the answer you can use this comment section. If you have bigger follow-up questions, I would suggest playing around with this first, trying out small things to see if it works, then expanding it to the website you are making. Most things become more clear by simply playing around with them. If you still have questions, you can ask a new question where you post a [minimal example](/help/mcve) that we can use to reproduce the problem you have, a clear problem description and the intended behaviour of your code. If whatever you want to ask is truly private, you should

Comment: not discuss it with me, as I am just another person in the internet you do not know.